# How can I repeat the last VIM macro?

Tags: vim, vim-macros

I know how to repeat the last command in Vim. I use <kbd>.</kbd>.

But how can I repeat the last macro? It's a little non-comfortable to press <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> everytime I want to repeat it.

I tried with <kbd>.</kbd> but it just repeats the last command from the macro.

Is there a shorter way of doing that?

Comment: Read `:h 10.1` for a short, practical introduction to macros. It has all the answers.

Comment: @glts Thanks! Useful information.

Comment: It may be helpful to know that it is possible to do `3@q` if you would simply chain the macros - i.e. if you would otherwise type `@q@q@q`.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Yes, you can use <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd> to replay the last used macro.

As a bonus, use <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to replay the last `ex` command.  (And then that becomes the "last used macro" that can be repeated with <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>.)

Comment: awesome :D :D :D :D

Answer (score 9):

I find <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd> a bit hard to type and as I don't use `,` much - and it's close enough to `.`:

```
:map , @@
```

Comment: genius! That helps a lot